# Concat Stream of String and Integer

Tags: java-8, stream, java-stream, method-reference

I am learning Stream and during one such practice session i was trying to join 2 streams of different type String and Integer via below code:

```
Stream<String> fruitStream = Stream.of("Apple", "Mango", "Muskmalon", "Guvava");
Stream<Integer> vegetablesStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4);

Stream<String> mixStream = Stream.concat(fruitStream, vegetablesStream.map(i -> i.toString()));
mixStream.forEach(System.out :: println);
```

It worked properly and gave me desired result.

Then i tried using Method Reference:

```
Stream<String> mixStream = Stream.concat(fruitStream, vegetablesStream.map(Integer :: toString));
```

And it started throwing error:

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.util.stream.Stream<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.util.stream.Stream<? extends T>'
concat (java.util.stream.Stream<? extends T>, java.util.stream.Stream<? extends T>) in Stream cannot be applied to (java.util.stream.Stream<java.lang.String>, java.util.stream.Stream<R>)   
reason: No compile-time declaration for the method reference is found
```

When i replaced my Method Reference with String :: ValueOf, it is working fine:

```
Stream<String> mixStream = Stream.concat(fruitStream, vegetablesStream.map(String :: valueOf));
```

> I am unable to understand why *Integer :: toString* failed but *String ::
>   valueOf* passed?

Comment: I knew that this had to be a duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message should be `Ambiguous method reference: both toString() and toString(int) from the type Integer are eligible`. That happens because both `toString` and `toString(int)` are eligible to be used here.

It could have been both:

```
  .map(i -> i.toString(i))
  .map(i -> i.toString())
```

And it works fine because `String::valueOf` has no such overloaded method and thus the compiler is fine with that.

Comment: Thank you Eugene for the clarification.. My apologies for the duplicate question but i was not able to find the exact same scenario.. Perhaps i will have to ump my search skills :)

Comment: Object::toString will work as well.  I ran into this issue when IntelliJ flagged a lambda "i -> i.toString()" with "Can be replaced with a method reference". I assume this message is generated as a result of a simple syntax check without taking possible ambiguity into account?

Comment: @GregH considering how *many* things could fit into this method reference replacer, I guess only the syntax check is the sane thing to report; after all IntelliJ is not into mind reading